# Leaflet map is not showing the line from gpx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I am having a weird issue with the leaflet.js map. For some reason, the trail line does not appear on the map even though it shows all the markers. It works fine in a standalone simple html page but whenever I embed this in the bootstrap template it breaks. My MVC .chtml page has the following code and jquery is referenced from the Layout page.

```
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key>" async defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-easybutton@2.0.0/src/easy-button.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-easybutton@2.0.0/src/easy-button.js"></script>
    <script src='~/Scripts/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js'></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/MarkerCluster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/MarkerCluster.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/GPX.js"></script>
     <div id="mapView">
                        <!-- This is the div that will contain the Google Map -->
                        <div id="lmap"></div>

                    </div>
<scripts>
    $(function(e){

        var lcontrol = new L.control.layers();
        var eb = new L.control.layers();
        //initialize map
        var map = null;
        var markers = [];
        var latlng = L.latLng(-30.81881, 116.16596);
       //set the layers
        var roadMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ type: 'roadmap' });
        var satMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ maxZoom: 24, type: 'satellite' });
        var terrainMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ maxZoom: 24, type: 'terrain' });
        var hybridMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({ maxZoom: 24, type: 'hybrid' });


        map = new L.map('lmap', {
            center: latlng, zoom: 6, maxZoom: 18, scrollwheel: false, layers: [roadMutant],
            streetViewControl: false, scrollWheelZoom: false, 
        });

        var track = new L.GPX("/media/fells_loop.gpx", {
            async: true
        }).on("loaded", function (e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        });
        map.addLayer(track);

        map.on('focus', function () { map.scrollWheelZoom.enable(); });
        map.on('blur', function () { map.scrollWheelZoom.disable(); });

    var baseLayers = {
            "Streets": roadMutant,
            "Satellite": satMutant,
            "Terrain": terrainMutant,
            "Hybrid": hybridMutant,

        };

    map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers(baseLayers, { 'GPX': track }, { collapsed: true }));
}
</scripts>
```

The clustering use jQuery get request to fetch data like below -

```
 markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true, spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true, maxClusterRadius: 100, showCoverageOnHover: true });

        //map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        //    map.removeLayer(layer);
        //});
        L.Map.include({
            'clearLayers': function () {
                this.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                    this.removeLayer(layer);
                }, this);
            }
        });

    //clear markers and remove all layers
        markers.clearLayers();
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();

    var atype = $('input:checkbox:checked.gp1').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get(); // ["18", "55", "10"]

    var st = atype + "";
    //fetch data
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: appUrl + "/Home/map", 
        data: {'atype': st},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var img = (item.IconUrl).replace("~", "");
                var dpawIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: appUrl + img, iconSize: [42, 42] });
                var id;
                var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), { icon: dpawIcon }, { title: item.Name });
                var content = "<div class='infoDiv'><h3><img src='" + appUrl + img + "' width='24' />" + item.Name + "</h3><p>" + item.Title + "</p><a href='#' data-value='" + item.AlertId + "' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#alertDetails'>Details</a></div>";
                id = marker._leaflet_id;
                marker.bindPopup(content);
                markers.addLayer(marker);

            });
        }

    })
   .done(function () {
       $(".loadingOverlay").hide();

      // $("#lmap").height(h-100).width(w-210);
       map.invalidateSize(true);

   });
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you don't have any error messages in your JavaScript console: Try to peel of 'extra' functionality until the polyline appears.

Comment: I think it is something to do with the clustering plugin. It works fine if I don't use the marker clustering.

Comment: @Tajuddin Then there is not enough information in your question in order to help you. Nowhere in your JS code you call the clustering plugin.

Comment: Sorry I have removed the clustering section to reduce the code block. I have added now in the original post.

Comment: So you are actually making 2 AJAX calls: 1 for your GPX, and 1 for your JSON markers to be clustered. When you say "It works fine if I don't use the marker clustering", do you mean it works if you get rid of the 2nd AJAX call, or if you replace `L.markerClusterGroup` by `L.featureGroup`? BTW you do not seem to add `markers` to the map.

Comment: Yes, it works fine if I don't use clustering plugin. Sorry I have probably opted the markers line since I had a lot of other irrelevant code to this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem after separating all css, js and other scripts files to narrow down to the root cause of the issue. It was actually the custom CSS file which has svg width attribute was set to 100%. I have removed that line and it is working fine now. Removed the following line.

```
svg { width: 100%; }
```

Hope this might help others with the similar issues.